# Return type value if RunTimeException has been thrown and not catched

Tags: java, exception, gson

I am using [Gson](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/) to parse Json. What I don't understand what the return type will be if you don't catch the [Runtime Exception](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.4-beta/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)). I was expecting it to be `null`, but it is not `null` when evaluating with a simple `if` statement.

My code looks something like this:

```
public X x(final String jsonString) {
   return gson.fromJson(jsonString, X.class);
}
```

then from another function I call the function:

```
public void y() {
  final X x = x();
  if (x == null) {
    System.out.println("x == null");
  }
}
```

I was expecting x to be null, but it isn't because the print statement is not called? What is the value of `x`? I have solved my problem by using a catch block in the `x()` function and returning `null` from inside the catch block. But I am just wondering what the value of function `x()` is(if any?)? Hopefully I make any sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `x()` is throwing an exception, the `x` variable remains uninitialized, since the control flow was interrupted. Without a try/catch, the exception keeps going up the stack and `x` is never usable. With a try/catch, `x` is only valid within the block, so if an exception happens it won't be usable.

If you try to do something like:

```
X x;
try {
    x = x();
} catch(RuntimeException e) {}
if (x == null) {
    ...
```

you'll get the error "variable x might not have been initialized", since control flow can bypass the assignment